Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 installation problem
The installation fails.
I had Ubuntu 20.04 but did not use often. I logged onto it and ran the update (600MB+). Upon completion it told me I had to do a system restart. I did. After the restart, I was able to access the terminal, but "sudo" was missing. I then discovered I could not access the internet. I then discovered the update program would not start.
After several attempts I just downloaded 24.04.1 and made a DL DVD for installing. It failed with messages about Nvidia and ics2. I finally booted back to Windows 10, removed all the partitions in hopes that it was something old that is corrupted causing the problems. No such luck.
Messages while trying to install (I stopped much sooner this last try, after maybe 10 minutes).
[ 223.979606] nvidia=gpu 0000:02:00
i2c timeout error 00000000
[223.979631] ics1_ccg 1-0008: i2c transfer failed -110  (not sure if wasn't 1-0000 poor vision)
[223.979643] ics1_ccg_init failed -110

Then I got a big cross like cursor and a white page that said an error occurred and offered button to logout (only option).
Nothing else happened. When I tried earlier I waited about 45 minutes and got 2 additional lines.
When I hit the reset button a screen full of stuff flew by and then the DVD reader opened ejecting the DVD.
I wish I had more information. I worked in a system's shop and know what I gave is basically useless.
Specs:
   Intel i7-4770K
   ASRock Z87 Extreme 4
   32GB RAM
   EVGA NVidia Geforce GTX 1660Ti
   Hauppauge quadHD TV-tuner card
   ASMedia 24 Port SATA III card

I'll suggest not trying to install from optical media; as the media will self-verify in the background, and unless you're patient waiting for that to complete; it can introduce timeout issues that the installer can misinterpret as hardware issues, meaning you need to check yourself from text terminal as to what the issue is. Did you perform any of these checks? Had media validation completed & reported all good?

Please forgive a very dumb question, but how do I install otherwise?  My hardware does not recognize booting from a thumb drive.  I guess, I could use VMWare and install to the device hard drive from the .iso file.  If I build that way, would the drive work at hardware power on for booting?  To be honest, going all the way back to my Amiga days, before that working on Univac minicomputers, I have always installed an OS during system startup.  I did not know it was possible otherwise.  I guess that is something taught to computer science students.

I have rebooted and entered BIOS setup.  There is no option for booting from a USB device.  I can only boot from an optical drive or from a regular disk drive (HDD or SSD no including SSD that are NVMe M.2 which my motherboard does have).

Thank you.  I called a friend with a more recent computer.  He said come over so I built the USB thumb drive using RUFUS, we connected the SSD using a SATA III to USB3.0 cable, built the SSD. and tested it.  I came home and am running off it.  Having problems with Hauppauge quadHD tv tuner, but I  all else looks good.
